# Deprecation error when using imageio.ffmpeg.download()

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge the prerecorded videos using python Opencv.
But i'm getting the error while importing.

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "video.py", line 4, in <module>
    from moviepy. editor import VideoFileClip,concatenate_videoclips 
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/moviepy/editor.py", line 26, in <module>
    imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/imageio/plugins/ffmpeg.py", line 40, in download
    "imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. "
RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'"
```

would anyone please help to get out of this problem

Here is the code:

```
import cv2 
import os 
import time 
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip,concatenate_videoclips 
def vidcapt():
    a = time.strftime("%H,%M,%S")
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(a+'.avi', fourcc, 24.0, (640,480))
    t1 = time.time()
    while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read() 
            if ret == True:
                    out.write(frame)
                    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
                    t2 = time.time()
                    time_diff = t2-t1
                    if time_diff >= 5:
                            break
            else:
                    break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

while True:
        vidcapt()


clip1 = VideoFileClip("11,05,42.avi")
clip2 = VideoFileClip("11,05,47.avi").subclip(50,60)
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2])
final_clip.write_videofile("merged.avi")
```

Comment: Have you tried using `pip install imageio-ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this instead:

```
sudo pip3 install imageio==2.4.1
```

hope to solve your issue.

Comment: with anaconda: conda install imageio=2.4.1

Answer (score 1):

you need to install `imageio-ffmpeg` along with `imageio`.

So install both of these packages with specified versions

`pip3 install imageio==2.4.1`

`pip install imageio-ffmpeg`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Or, simply comment those two lines in editor.py, that refer to an already deprecated function

```py
#if os.getenv('FFMPEG_BINARY', 'ffmpeg-imageio') == 'ffmpeg-imageio':
#    imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's:

```
imageio_download_bin ffmpeg
```

Or:

```
conda install ffmpeg -c conda-forge
```

Or:

```
imageio.plugins.ffmpeg.download()
```