# RuntimeError: imageio.ffmpeg.download() has been deprecated. Use 'pip install imageio-ffmpeg' instead.'

Tags: python, runtime-error, moviepy, python-imageio

I'm trying to run the Lane-detection Project from [here](https://github.com/Nallo/CarND-P4-Advanced-Lane-Lines/blob/master/notebooks/pipeline.ipynb) with the Jupiter notebook.
I get this Runtime-Error:

[Picture of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kpa3a.png)

When I try to run this code:

```
# Import everything needed to edit/save/watch video clips
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
from IPython.display import HTML
```

I already tried to install the latest version of `moviepy` with `conda install -c conda-forge moviepy`.
I also tried to install with pip but still the same error.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!! It would be great if you could [read these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Always remember to do a good research before make a question on StackOverflow. This question is already answered on the SuperUser site and simply a normal search on the error sent me to there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deprecation error when using imageio.ffmpeg.download()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54803180/deprecation-error-when-using-imageio-ffmpeg-download)

Answer (score 16):

The updated version of `imageio` causes this error.

Using the imageio on version 2.4.1 will solve your problem:

```
sudo pip3 install imageio==2.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to downgrade the moviepy to 1.0.3. All the steps above didn't work for me but this one did.

```
pip install moviepy=1.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by creating a new conda environment with python=3.6.5 and imageio=2.4.1.

```
$ conda list | grep python
ipython                   7.11.1           py36h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
opencv-python             4.1.2.30                 pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.5                hc3d631a_2  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
$ conda list | grep imageio
imageio                   2.4.1                 py36_1000    conda-forge
$ conda list | grep moviepy
moviepy                   0.2.3.5                    py_0    conda-forge
$ conda list | grep tensorflow
tensorflow                1.14.0          gpu_py36h3fb9ad6_0  
tensorflow-base           1.14.0          gpu_py36he45bfe2_0  
tensorflow-estimator      1.14.0                     py_0  
tensorflow-gpu            1.14.0               h0d30ee6_0  
$ conda list | grep ffmpeg
ffmpeg                    4.2                  h167e202_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this procedure. This worked for me.

**Install this requriments:**

1. `!pip install moviepy`
2. `!pip3 install imageio==2.4.1`
3. `!pip install --upgrade imageio-ffmpeg`

If you run the code, it still raises the same error. Now, click on the `editor.py` path link that appears in the error: [image]

Go to lines 25 and 26 and comment them out.